# How do I update a table inside a python interface on Tkinter with input?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, tkinter, sql-update

I am developing a python interface with login and an information table, but I found an obstacle that is preventing me from moving.

I have tried to make the user able to modify (or update) a data table. At first I thought I would just need to give the row id and the chosen column for the user to be able to update the data, but unfortunately for some reason, none of my attempted commands worked.

Below is my last failed attempt:

```
            def changeconfirmed():
                escolha = entry.get()
                entrada = entry2.get()
                Id = entry3.get()

                if escolha == "Nome":
                    funcao = entrada, Id
                    banco = ("""
                    UPDATE Navio SET Nome = %s WHERE Id = %s
                    """)
                    Banco.cursor.execute(banco, funcao)
                    Banco.conn.commit()
                    print("update successfully")
```

Some words are in Portuguese because I'm Brazilian and to make it easier to use them as directional.
I tried to use several forms of SQL UPDATE command, none worked, especially this one using "% s", the interpreter says that it does not recognize the '%'. Unfortunately that's all that prevents me from finishing the interface, as data entry and deletion work normally(The WHERE command is not recognized either.).

How can I update the table with data entered by the user?

Entire code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import Banco
import sqlite3
import random


def update():
    l.config(text=str(random.random()))
    jan.after(1000, update)


jan = Tk()
jan.title("RESTRITO")
jan.geometry("500x405")
jan.configure(background="#585858", highlightcolor="#cfc91c", highlightbackground="#cfc91c", highlightthickness=10)
jan.resizable(width=False, height=False)

# mapa
LeftFrame = Frame(jan, width=310, height=120, bg="#cfc91c")
LeftFrame.place(x=85, y=50)
label1Frame = Frame(jan, width=310, height=50, bg="#cfc91c")
label1Frame.place(x=85, y=180)
label2Frame = Frame(jan, width=310, height=50, bg="#cfc91c")
label2Frame.place(x=85, y=220)
buttonFrame = Frame(jan, width=200, height=50, bg="#cfc91c")
buttonFrame.place(x=140, y=280)
# termina aqui mapa

# titulo e texto
Acessolabel = Label(LeftFrame, text="Acesso Restrito", font=("Arial", 20, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
Acessolabel.place(x=3, y=10)
texto1label = Label(LeftFrame, text="Este programa é de uso restrito ", font=("Arial", 14), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
texto1label.place(x=3, y=50)
texto2label = Label(LeftFrame, text="para somente pessoas autorizadas.", font=("Arial", 14), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
texto2label.place(x=3, y=80)
# temina aqui titulo e texto

# usuario e senha entrada
userLabel1 = Label(label1Frame, text="Usuário:", font=("Arial", 16, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
userLabel1.place(x=17, y=10)
userLabel2 = Label(label2Frame, text="Senha:", font=("Arial", 16, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
userLabel2.place(x=18, y=8)

userUsuario = ttk.Entry(label1Frame, width=30)
userUsuario.place(x=105, y=13)
userSenha = ttk.Entry(label2Frame, width=30, show="*")
userSenha.place(x=105, y=11)
# termina aqui usuario e senha entrada

# login comando


def login():
    user = userUsuario.get()
    password = userSenha.get()
    Banco.cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM Users
    WHERE User = ? and Password = ?
    """, (user, password))
    print("Clicou!")
    verifylogin = Banco.cursor.fetchone()
    try:
        if user in verifylogin and password in verifylogin:
            print("Parabéns!")

            conn = sqlite3.connect("UserData.db")
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            # SQL
            sql2 = "SELECT TOX, Quantidade, QDM FROM TOXICO"
            cursor.execute(sql2)
            rows2 = cursor.fetchall()
            total1 = cursor.rowcount
            print("number entry's table:" + str(total1))
            sql = "SELECT Id, Nome, Idade, Situação FROM Navio"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            total2 = cursor.rowcount
            print("number entry's:"+str(total2))

            # movendo tela de login
            LeftFrame.place(x=501)
            label1Frame.place(x=501)
            label2Frame.place(x=501)
            buttonFrame.place(x=501)
            # termina aqui movendo tela de login

            # mapa
            topFrame = Frame(jan, width=440, height=100, bg="#cfc91c", relief="raise")
            topFrame.place(x=20, y=20)

            topFrame2 = Frame(jan, width=440, height=50, bg="#cfc91c", relief="raise")
            topFrame2.place(x=20, y=90)

            centerframe = Frame(jan, width=150, height=227, bg="#cfc91c", relief="raise")
            centerframe.place(x=20, y=140)

            centerframe2 = Frame(jan, width=290, height=227, bg="#cfc91c", relief="raise")
            centerframe2.place(x=170, y=140)
            # termina aqui mapa

            # labels
            titulolabel = Label(topFrame, text="Sistema de Informações", font=("Arial", 20, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c",
                                fg="#585858")
            titulolabel.place(x=55, y=25)

            # termina aqui labels

            # "#585858" "#cfc91c"

            # funções

            def Return():
                # removendo tela de informações
                topFrame.place(x=501)
                topFrame2.place(x=501)
                centerframe.place(x=501)
                centerframe2.place(x=501)
                fecharb.place(x=501)
                # voltando a tela de login
                LeftFrame.place(x=85)
                label1Frame.place(x=85)
                label2Frame.place(x=85)
                buttonFrame.place(x=140)

            def trip():
                # botões
                botao3.place(x=15, y=15)
                botao4.place(x=15, y=55)
                botao5.place(x=15, y=95)
                # termina aqui botões

                # puxar tabela TRIPULAÇÃO
                tree1.place(x=0)
                # termina aqui  puxar tabela TRIPULAÇÃO

                # remover tabela TOXICO
                tree2.place(x=500)
                # termina aqui remover tabela TOXICO

                # esconder
                entry.place(x=401)
                entry1.place(x=401)
                entry2.place(x=401)
                entry3.place(x=401)
                entry4.place(x=441)

                botao6.place(x=401)
                botao7.place(x=401)
                botao8.place(x=401)
                botao61.place(x=401)
                botao71.place(x=401)
                botao81.place(x=401)
                insert.place(x=401)
                change.place(x=401)
                excluirtrash.place(x=401)

                labelid.place(x=401)
                labelid2.place(x=401)
                labelid3.place(x=441)
                labelid5.place(x=401)
                labelid11.place(x=401)
                labelid21.place(x=401)
                labelid41.place(x=401)

                MT.place(x=401)
                QT.place(x=401)
                QDM.place(x=441)

                botao61.place(x=401)
                botao71.place(x=401)
                botao81.place(x=401)

            def tox():
                # botões
                insert.place(x=15, y=15)
                change.place(x=15, y=55)
                excluirtrash.place(x=15, y=95)
                # termina aqui botões

                # puxar tabela TOXICO
                tree2.place(x=0)
                # termina aqui puxar tabela TOXICO

                # remover tabela TRIPULAÇÃO
                tree1.place(x=500)
                # termina aqui remover tabela TRIPULAÇÃO

                # esconder
                entry.place(x=401)
                entry1.place(x=401)
                entry2.place(x=401)
                entry3.place(x=401)
                entry4.place(x=441)

                botao6.place(x=401)
                botao7.place(x=401)
                botao8.place(x=401)
                botao61.place(x=401)
                botao71.place(x=401)
                botao81.place(x=401)

                labelid.place(x=401)
                labelid2.place(x=401)
                labelid3.place(x=441)
                labelid5.place(x=401)
                labelid11.place(x=401)
                labelid21.place(x=401)
                labelid41.place(x=401)

                MT.place(x=401)
                QT.place(x=401)
                QDM.place(x=441)

                botao61.place(x=401)
                botao71.place(x=401)
                botao81.place(x=401)

            def insert():
                botao6.place(x=80, y=15)

                entry.place(x=15, y=150)
                entry2.place(x=15, y=195)
                entry4.place(x=285, y=12)

                labelid.place(x=15, y=125)
                labelid2.place(x=15, y=170)
                labelid3.place(x=220, y=12)

                # esconder
                botao7.place(x=401)
                botao8.place(x=401)

                entry1.place(x=401)
                entry3.place(x=401)

                labelid5.place(x=401)
                labelid11.place(x=401)
                labelid21.place(x=401)
                labelid41.place(x=401)

                botao61.place(x=401)
                botao71.place(x=401)
                botao81.place(x=401)

                MT.place(x=401)
                QT.place(x=401)
                QDM.place(x=441)

            def insertconfirmed():
                entrada2 = entry2.get()
                entrada = entry.get()
                entrada3 = entry4.get()

                banco = """INSERT INTO Navio(Nome, idade, Situação) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"""
                entrada1 = entrada, entrada2, entrada3
                cursor.execute(banco, entrada1)
                conn.commit()
                print("deu certo nome!")

            def change():
                botao7.place(x=80, y=55)

                entry.place(x=15, y=150)
                entry2.place(x=15, y=195)
                entry3.place(x=110, y=95)

                labelid5.place(x=80, y=95)
                labelid11.place(x=15, y=125)
                labelid21.place(x=15, y=170)

                # esconder
                botao6.place(x=401)
                botao8.place(x=401)
                botao61.place(x=401)
                botao71.place(x=401)
                botao81.place(x=401)

                labelid41.place(x=401)
                labelid.place(x=401)
                labelid2.place(x=401)
                labelid3.place(x=441)

                MT.place(x=401)
                QT.place(x=401)
                QDM.place(x=441)

                entry1.place(x=401)
                entry4.place(x=441)

            def changeconfirmed():
                escolha = entry.get()
                entrada = entry2.get()
                Id = entry3.get()

                if escolha == "Nome":
                    funcao = entrada, Id
                    banco = ("""
                    UPDATE Navio SET Nome = %s WHERE Id = %s
                    """, funcao)
                    Banco.cursor.execute(banco, funcao)
                    Banco.conn.commit()
                    print("update successfully")
                elif escolha == "Idade":
                    banco = "Update Navio set Idade = %s where Id = %s"
                    funcao = entrada, Id
                    cursor.execute(banco, funcao)
                    Banco.conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo idade!")
                elif escolha == "Situação":
                    banco = "Update Navio set Situação = %s where Id = %s"
                    funcao = entrada, Id
                    cursor.execute(banco, funcao)
                    Banco.conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo situação!")

            def trash():
                botao8.place(x=80, y=95)
                entry1.place(x=15, y=150)
                labelid41.place(x=15, y=125)


                # esconder
                botao7.place(x=401)
                botao6.place(x=401)
                botao61.place(x=401)
                botao71.place(x=401)
                botao81.place(x=401)

                entry.place(x=401)
                entry2.place(x=401)
                entry3.place(x=401)
                entry4.place(x=441)

                labelid.place(x=401)
                labelid2.place(x=401)
                labelid3.place(x=441)
                labelid5.place(x=401)
                labelid11.place(x=401)
                labelid21.place(x=401)
                MT.place(x=401)
                QT.place(x=401)
                QDM.place(x=441)

            def trashconfirmed():
                entrada = entry.get()

                if entrada == "1":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 1"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 1!")
                elif entrada == "2":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 2"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 2!")
                elif entrada == "3":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 3"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 3!")
                elif entrada == "4":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 4"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 4!")
                elif entrada == "5":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 5"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 5!")
                elif entrada == "6":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 6"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 6!")
                elif entrada == "7":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 7"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 7!")
                elif entrada == "8":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 8"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 8!")
                elif entrada == "9":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 9"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 9!")
                elif entrada == "10":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 10"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 10!")
                elif entrada == "11":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 11"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 11!")
                elif entrada == "12":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 12"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 12!")
                elif entrada == "13":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 13"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 13!")
                elif entrada == "14":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 14"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 14!")
                elif entrada == "15":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM Navio WHERE id = 15"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 15!")

            def insert2():
                botao61.place(x=80, y=15)

                entry.place(x=15, y=150)
                entry2.place(x=15, y=195)
                entry4.place(x=280, y=12)

                MT.place(x=15, y=125)
                QT.place(x=15, y=170)
                QDM.place(x=220, y=12)

                botao71.place(x=441)
                botao81.place(x=441)
                labelid5.place(x=401)
                entry1.place(x=401)
                entry3.place(x=401)

            def insertconfirmed2():
                entrada2 = entry2.get()
                entrada = entry.get()
                entrada3 = entry4.get()

                banco = """INSERT INTO TOXICO(TOX, Quantidade, QDM) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"""
                entrada1 = entrada, entrada2, entrada3
                cursor.execute(banco, entrada1)
                conn.commit()
                print("deu certo nome!")

            def change2():
                botao71.place(x=80, y=55)

                entry.place(x=15, y=150)
                entry2.place(x=15, y=195)
                entry3.place(x=110, y=95)
                entry4.place(x=280, y=12)

                labelid5.place(x=80, y=95)

                MT.place(x=15, y=125)
                QT.place(x=15, y=170)
                QDM.place(x=220, y=12)


                # esconder
                botao6.place(x=401)
                labelid41.place(x=401)
                botao8.place(x=401)
                botao61.place(x=401)
                botao81.place(x=441)
                entry1.place(x=401)

            def changeconfirmed2():
                escolha = entry.get()
                entrada = entry2.get()
                Id = entry3.get()

                if escolha == "Material Tóxico":
                    banco = ("""
                    UPDATE INTO TOXICO(TOX) VALUES(TEXT)
                    """)
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    Banco.conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo nome!")
                elif escolha == "Quantidade":
                    Banco.cursor.execute("""
                               UPDATE INTO TOXICO(Quantidade) VALUES(TEXT)
                               """, Id, entrada)
                    Banco.conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo idade!")
                elif escolha == "Q. Despejada no Mar":
                    Banco.cursor.execute("""
                               UPDATE INTO TOXICO(QMD) VALUES(TEXT)
                               """, Id, entrada)
                    Banco.conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo situação!")

            def trash2():
                botao81.place(x=80, y=95)
                entry1.place(x=15, y=150)
                labelid41.place(x=15, y=125)

                # esconder
                botao7.place(x=401)
                botao6.place(x=401)
                botao61.place(x=401)
                botao71.place(x=401)

                entry.place(x=401)
                entry2.place(x=401)
                entry3.place(x=401)
                entry4.place(x=441)

                labelid.place(x=401)
                labelid2.place(x=401)
                labelid3.place(x=441)
                labelid5.place(x=401)
                MT.place(x=401)
                QT.place(x=401)
                QDM.place(x=441)

            def trashconfirmed2():
                entrada = entry1.get()

                if entrada == "1":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM TOXICO WHERE id = 1"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 1!")
                elif entrada == "2":
                    banco = """DELETE FROM TOXICO WHERE id = 2"""
                    cursor.execute(banco)
                    conn.commit()
                    print("deu certo 2!")

            # termina aqui funções

            # botões MENU E TABELAS
            fecharb = Button(jan, text="←", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                             command=Return)
            fecharb.place(x=20, y=20)
            botao1 = Button(topFrame2, text="Tripulação", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=trip)
            botao1.place(x=20, y=10)
            botao2 = Button(topFrame2, text="Sub. Tóxicas", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=tox)
            botao2.place(x=112, y=10)
            botao3 = Button(centerframe, text="Inserir:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=insert)
            botao3.place(x=441)
            insert = Button(centerframe, text="Inserir:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=insert2)
            insert.place(x=441)
            botao4 = Button(centerframe, text="Alterar:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=change)
            botao4.place(x=441)
            change = Button(centerframe, text="Alterar:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=change2)
            change.place(x=441)
            botao5 = Button(centerframe, text="Excluir:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=trash)
            botao5.place(x=441)
            excluirtrash = Button(centerframe, text="Excluir:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=trash2)
            excluirtrash.place(x=441)

            # botoes para confirmar
            botao6 = Button(centerframe, text="Inserir!", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=insertconfirmed)
            botao6.place(x=441)
            botao61 = Button(centerframe, text="Inserir!", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=insertconfirmed2)
            botao61.place(x=441)
            botao7 = Button(centerframe, text="Alterar!", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=changeconfirmed)
            botao7.place(x=441)
            botao71 = Button(centerframe, text="Alterar!", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=changeconfirmed2)
            botao71.place(x=441)
            botao8 = Button(centerframe, text="Excluir!", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=trashconfirmed)
            botao8.place(x=441)
            botao81 = Button(centerframe, text="Excluir!", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c",
                            command=trashconfirmed2)
            botao81.place(x=441)
            # termina aqui botoes para confirmar
            # termina aqui botões

            # labels da entrada TABELAS
            labelid = Label(centerframe, text="Nome:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            labelid.place(x=401)
            labelid2 = Label(centerframe, text="Idade:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            labelid2.place(x=401)

            labelid11 = Label(centerframe, text="Nome da Coluna:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            labelid11.place(x=401)
            labelid21 = Label(centerframe, text="Entrada:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            labelid21.place(x=401)

            labelid3 = Label(topFrame2, text="Situação:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            labelid3.place(x=441)
            labelid4 = Label(centerframe, text="Excluir:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            labelid4.place(x=401)
            labelid41 = Label(centerframe, text="Excluir Linha Id:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            labelid41.place(x=401)
            labelid5 = Label(centerframe, text="Id:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            labelid5.place(x=401)

            MT = Label(centerframe, text="Material Tóxico:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            MT.place(x=401)
            QT = Label(centerframe, text="Quantidade:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            QT.place(x=401)
            QDM = Label(topFrame2, text="Q.D.M.:", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), bg="#cfc91c", fg="#585858")
            QDM.place(x=441)
            # termina aqui labels da entrada TABELAS

            # entrada TABELAS
            entry = ttk.Entry(centerframe, width=19)
            entry.place(y=500)
            entry1 = ttk.Entry(centerframe, width=3)
            entry1.place(y=500)
            entry2 = ttk.Entry(centerframe, width=19)
            entry2.place(y=500)
            entry3 = ttk.Entry(centerframe, width=3)
            entry3.place(y=500)
            entry4 = ttk.Entry(topFrame2, width=19)
            entry4.place(x=500)
            # termina aqui entrada

            # tabela TRIPULAÇÃO
            tree1 = ttk.Treeview(centerframe2, selectmode="extended", columns=("x", "z", "A", "B"), height=10)
            tree1.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
            tree1.place(x=500)
            tree1.heading("#0", text="")
            tree1.column("#0", minwidth=0, width=-1)
            tree1.heading("x", text="Id")
            tree1.column("x", minwidth=0, width=20)
            tree1.heading("A", text="Idade")
            tree1.column("A", minwidth=0, width=40)
            tree1.heading("B", text="Situação")
            tree1.column("B", minwidth=0, width=96)
            tree1.heading("z", text="Nome")
            tree1.column("z", minwidth=0, width=152)
            # termina aqui tabela

            # tabela TOXICO
            tree2 = ttk.Treeview(centerframe2, selectmode="extended", columns=("A", "B", "C"),  height=10)
            tree2.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
            tree2.place(x=500)
            tree2.heading("#0")
            tree2.column("#0", minwidth=0, width=-1, stretch=NO)
            tree2.heading("A", text="Material Tóxico")
            tree2.column("A", minwidth=0, width=92)
            tree2.heading("B", text="Quantidade")
            tree2.column("B", minwidth=0, width=72)
            tree2.heading("C", text="Q. Despejada no Mar")
            tree2.column("C", minwidth=0, width=125)

            # termina aqui tabela

            # função sql
            for i in rows:
                tree1.insert('', 'end', values=i)

            for i in rows2:
                tree2.insert('', 'end', values=i)


    except:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="", message="ACESSO NEGADO. POR FAVOR MANTENHA DISTÂNCIA DO NAVIO.")
# termina aqui login comando


# botao
EntrarBotao = Button(buttonFrame, text="Entrar", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'), width=15, command=login, bg="#585858", fg="#cfc91c")
EntrarBotao.place(x=35, y=12)
# termina aqui botao

l = tk.Label()
l.pack()
l.place(x=501)
jan.after(1000, update)
jan.update()
jan.mainloop()
```

References:
Inserir = Insert 
Alterar = Change 
Excluir = Delete 
Entrada = Input 
Escolha = Choice

DataBase Code:
save the file as "Banco.py"

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("UserData.db")

cursor = conn.cursor()

print("Successfully connected")
```

Table Information:
There are 4 tables

```
CREATE TABLE "Navio" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Nome"  TEXT,
    "Idade" INTEGER,
    "Situação"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE "TOXICO" (
    "Id"    INTEGER,
    "TOX"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Quantidade"    TEXT,
    "QDM"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id")
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE "Users" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "User"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Password"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Comment: Please don't post so much code. Try to whittle the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: Use `?` instead of `%s` in the SQL statement because you use SQLite3.

Answer (score 0):

I am grateful for those who tried to help me! Fortunately right now I managed to solve the problem, I will leave the solution here so that other people can also use it:

```
    entrada = entry.get()
    entrada2 = entry1.get()
    entrada3 = entry2.get()
    Id = entry3.get()
    banco = """UPDATE TOXICO SET TOX = ?, Quantidade = ?, QDM = ? WHERE Id = ? ;"""
    entrada1 = entrada, entrada2, entrada3, Id
    cursor.execute(banco, entrada1)
    conn.commit()
```

Work finished! I had tried it in many ways and this was the simplest and quickest, which in the end solved my problem.